# Does git contain information about used id / group id changes?

Tags: git

I have googling awhile, but can not find such information. Looks like git doesn't contain users and groups, only permissions. Am I right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See the [Content Limitations](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ContentLimitations) section of the git Wiki: git does not track file ownership, group membership, doesn't track most permission bits, ACLs, access and modification times, etc.

Git tracks contents, and doesn't care much about pretty much everything else.